# Kotlin build problems with Android

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin, kotlin-extension

Integrated Kotlin into a somewhat large project that uses multidex.

**So when I try to build, I get this error:**

`:incrementalDesygnerDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:compileDesygnerDebugKotlin
WARN: Failed to initialize native filesystem for Windows
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find installation home path. Please make sure bin/idea.properties is present in the installation directory.`

The paths seem to be configured correctly and `idea.properties` file seems to be there: `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\idea.properties`

The building takes a few minutes to stop, so I stop it manually from Task Manager on windows.

**When I retry - the build succeeds!**

But when I change a line, and rebuild it shows the same error again.

Sometimes I also get this one:

`The system is out of resources.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space`

Tried increasing all sorts of memory settings, but maybe not doing it right

`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx8g -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m` is what I have in `gradle.properties`

Tried with Instant Run on and off.

Project builds fine without Kotlin, tried Android Studio 2.0 stable, Kotlin stable, Kotlin EAP and AS Canary builds.

P.S `gradlew assembleDebug` works every time until I try building with AS.

**Edit: tried same project on:**

- Another Windows 10 PC -> same thing.
- OSX -> works without issues.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if the errors are linked but I've found that if I remove

`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms256m -Xmx9216M` from

`C:/Users/<user>/.gradle/gradle.properties` file the error is still there but the build succeeds everytime.

To reiterate:

- Kotlin + `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms256m -Xmx9216M` in `gradle.properties` - FAIL
- `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms256m -Xmx9216M` in `gradle.properties` - OK but with above error
- Kotlin - OK with above error

C.f. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11770